# Classification of affine varieties over the affine line whose central fiber is $\mathbb{C}$ and general fiber is $\mathbb{C}^*$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Consider an affine variety $Y$ equipped with a morphism $\pi: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. The conditions we have are that $\pi^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{C}$, and for any $x$ not equal to zero, $\pi^{-1}(x)=\mathbb{C}^*$. Is it possible to find a complete list of such $Y$?

For example, the affine blow up of $({\mathbb{C}^*})^2$ at $(1,1)$, which could be defined as $Y=\{(x,y,u)\in\mathbb{C}^3\mid x^2-uy^2=y\}$ with projection to $\mathbb{C}_u$.

Comment: Not sure about a classification, but an easier example is $\mathbf A^2 \setminus V(xy-1)$ projecting (via first or second projection) to $\mathbf A^1$. If you want to embed into an affine space, take $\{(x,y,u) \in \mathbf A^3\ |\ u(xy-1) = 1\}$, which looks a little similar (but not identical) to your example.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you for providing an example. Could you please explain why they are not identical?

Comment: By 'not identical' I really mean that: not *identical* (i.e. the equations differ). I don't know whether they are *isomorphic*.

Comment: There exists a unique projective model of the generic fiber.  The generic fiber is an open subset of this projective model.  The closed complement of this open subset is a finite, etale extension of the function field $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of degree $2$.  By the hypotheses, this extension is either $\mathbb{C}(x)\times \mathbb{C}(x)$ or $\mathbb{C}(x)[y]/\langle y^2 -x\rangle$.  Both of these occur.

Comment: Actually the comment is okay (I forgot that the OP wants $Y$ to be affine).

Comment: @JasonStarr, thank you for your comment. I am not very familiar with algebra, but I understood some of your idea. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that we perform partial compactification on each fiber within an ambient projective space. In this case, the boundary to the base $\mathbb{C}$ would be a 2-to-1 map, resulting in two distinct types of boundaries as you described. Does this imply that there is a proof that R.van's example is not isomorphic to mine? However, it is still unclear how many fibrations exist in each of these two cases.